# SQL query having trouble with

Tags: sql

I have a question about my teacher's SQL query. We are trying to find students who applied to CS but did not apply to EE.

```
Select sID, sName
From Student
Where sID = any (select sID from Apply where major = ‘CS’)
And sID <> any (select sID from Apply where major = ‘EE’)
```

The above query is apparently incorrect. I understand why it is incorrect. We are going to get sIDs of students who didn't apply to EE regardless of whether they applied to CS.

The below query is apparently the correct query. Why does the below query work?

```
Select sID, sName
From Student
Where sID = any (select sID from Apply where major = ‘CS’)
And not sID = any (select sID from Apply where major = ‘EE’)
```

Comment: They are both correct.  Neither is syntactically invalid.  `And Not .. = ...` behaves identically as `And ... <> ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
And a <> b
```

and

```
And not a = b
```

Are syntactically equivalent, and both are correct in achieving the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
not sID = any (select sID from Apply where major = ‘EE’)
```

is equivalent to:

```
sID <> all (select sID from Apply where major = ‘EE’)
```